# php's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI '] encoding problem?

Tags: php, encoding

When I output `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` on:

```
http://localhost/tools/?tool=cs&sub=1
```

I get:

```
/tools/?tool=cs⊂=1
```

Is there other solution to get `/tools/?tool=cs&sub=1` besides using `&amp;` instead of `&` ?

Comment: Using `&amp;` instead of `&` is *the* solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're echoing it to your browser - `&sub` is being interpreted as an HTML entity (⊂).

If you `echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` you'll get what you expect.

You have to use the right encoding for the environment you're in - in HTML that means using `&amp;`.

Comment: If you are working with UTF-8, I would recommend you using htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
echo urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you outputting this value? If you're dumping it to the browser, are you sure it's not trying to 'decode' embedded ampersands?

Try a file with just

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

and look to see what the value is displayed as (near the bottom)